# TouchTable - Are these just Microsoft Surface tablets?

Tags: pixelsense

I came across these guys, http://www.touchtable.com, and this technology just looks so much like MS Surface.  Does anyone know about them?

> 1) Is the hardware MS Surface tablets?
>
> 2) Is the code behind these UIs
>   Surface-based, i.e. XAML / .NET?

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not connected to Microsoft Surface at all.  However, WPF 4 and the Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957352.aspx) have an extensibility mechanism that will let you convert input from other systems (like TouchTable) and pump those input events into WPF 4 while making use of the Surface UI controls.  Here is an example of doing that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2010/01/30/custom-touch-devices.aspx.

Comment: Thanks!  I just find it hard to believe that a 'small' company would create their own hardware.  How do you know?

Comment: I worked on the Microsoft Surface team for 3 years :)  There are several small companies that sell multitouch hardware.  We created the "Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch" to give those companies an incentive to build on top of Windows 7: they get the benefits of Microsoft's investments in multitouch SDKs/UI frameworks/developer ecosystem instead of having to recreate their own from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't Microsoft Surface. Surface is vision based, so it can also recognize objects placed on the surface. This is touch-driven, so it won't recognize objects. Big difference.